# ¿Como hacer que la posicion dentro de un div sea 0 cuando arratro un div nuevo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, drag-and-drop

Guardo la posicion en mi tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que hago es arrastrar el div a el contenedor, pero me toma las medidas pero de todo el espacio, solo quiero que me tome la posicion en la que este el div hijo en el padre
este es mi codigo donde tomo la posicion
y me funciona cuando lo abro en el modal, me respeta la posicion pero al querer visualizarlo fuera de el modal no me respeta la posicion, y no se si se pueda tomar el tamaño del div padre como si fuera una nueva medida, o un nuevo contenedor sin tomar el espacio total del modal

```js
  function drop(e, idcredencial99, tipo) {
        var elementoArrastrado = e.dataTransfer.getData("Data"); // Elemento arrastrado
        e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(elementoArrastrado)); // Añade el elemento arrastrado al elemento desde el que se llama a esta funcion

        // Dimensiones del elemento sobre el que se arrastra
        tamContX = $('#' + e.target.id).width();
        tamContY = $('#' + e.target.id).height();

        // Dimensiones del elemento arrastrado
        tamElemX = $('#' + elementoArrastrado).width();
        tamElemY = $('#' + elementoArrastrado).height();

        // Posicion del elemento sobre el que se arrastra
        posXCont = $(e.target).position().left;
        posYCont = $(e.target).position().top;

        // Posicion absoluta del raton
        x = e.layerX;
        y = e.layerY;

        // Si parte del elemento que se quiere mover se queda fuera se cambia las coordenadas para que no sea asi
        if (posXCont + tamContX <= x + tamElemX) {
            x = posXCont + tamContX - tamElemX;
        }

        if (posYCont + tamContY <= y + tamElemY) {
            y = posYCont + tamContY - tamElemY;
        }

        document.getElementById(elementoArrastrado).style.position = "absolute";
        document.getElementById(elementoArrastrado).style.left = x + "px";
        document.getElementById(elementoArrastrado).style.top = y + "px";


        var posicionleft = $("#" + elementoArrastrado).css("left");
        var posiciontop = $("#" + elementoArrastrado).css("top");
        var posicionright = $("#" + elementoArrastrado).css("right");
        var color = $("#" + elementoArrastrado).css("color");
        var tamanoletra = $("#" + elementoArrastrado).css("font-size");
        // var negrita = $("#" + elementoArrastrado).attr("style");
        var negritavalor = $("#" + elementoArrastrado).css("font-weight");
        // $("#boton").attr("value")

        var dama = $("#" + elementoArrastrado).appendTo("#" + tipo);
        var tipocredencial = dama.parent().attr('id')

        var tamanologowidth = $("#" + elementoArrastrado).css("width");
        var tamanologoheight = $("#" + elementoArrastrado).css("height");

    
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "paneladm/guardadatoscredencial.php",
            data: {
                posicionleft: posicionleft,
                posiciontop: posiciontop,
                posicionright: posicionright,
                elementoArrastrado: elementoArrastrado,
                idcredencial99: idcredencial99,
                color: color,
                tamanoletra: tamanoletra,
                negrita: negritavalor,
                imagenwidth: tamanologowidth,
                imagenheight: tamanologoheight,
                tipofot: tipocredencial
            },
            success: function(response) {

            }
        });
      
        e.target.style.border = ''; // Quita el borde del cuadro al que se mueve
    }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías quizá agregar un poco de tu código?

Comment: No vemos ningún código de referencia, por la cual se nos hace imposible ayudarte...